# Why use Puppeteer for JS webscraping instead of just Ajax?

Tags: ajax, puppeteer

I have been using regular Ajax requests to pull HTML from a desired location using my Node server. However my peer has recently been using Puppeteer (a headless browser) to achieve roughly the same thing. Why use something like this?

Comment: Your HTTP request doesn't interact with the JS in real time--parsing and extracting information is a different task. See https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/#what-can-i-do

Comment: It's __Webscraping__ not webscrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just HTML source code, you usually need not a headless browser. But if you need a full-fledged document with all scripts executed and all dynamical data generated, you do need a headless browser.